# how to run cmd command netsh using notepad

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make autorun .bat program that automatically performs netsh cmd and save the result in .txt file by the just simple click of a button.

> below is what I wrote in notepad and saved as getkey.bat

```
echo netsh wlan show profile name=wifi_name key=clear >Desktop/savedpasskey.txt
exit
```

but it is not working

Comment: So what is the error message? Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: ECHO won't execute NETSH but just printout that line

Comment: So how to run command netsh automatically

Comment: @DavidPostill It is showing no error, just cmd prompt opens and no command execute

Comment: remove `start cmd`. remove `echo `

Comment: @DavidPostill removed those cmd's and tried running but still not working

Comment: Please copy and paste the command and output on the screen into the question.

Comment: I didn't know that **notepad** could _run cmd commands_!  **`:/`**  I suggest you to change the question title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. You can change the TEMPFILE to wherever you want the file to be created.

```
SET "TEMPFILE=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\savedpasskey.txt"
netsh wlan show profile name=wifi_name key=clear >"%TEMPFILE%"
TYPE "%TEMPFILE%"
```

Comment: To show the key the batch file should be executed with admin rights !

Comment: @Hackoo did i have to add any piece of code or it have to be done manually

Answer (score 3):

To show the password of your WIFI SSID , you must execute this batch file with admin rights :

```dos
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Copyright=by Hackoo 2017"
Title  %~n0 %Copyright%
Mode con cols=75 lines=8
cls & color 0A & echo.
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo                 %~n0 %Copyright%
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo(
if _%1_==_Main_  goto :Main
Set Count=0
Set L=0
:getadmin
    echo               %~nx0 : self elevating
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Main %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1
)> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof
::*************************************************************************************
:Main
Call :init
Call :CountLines
Set "PasswordLog=%~dp0Wifi_Passwords_on_%ComputerName%.txt"
%Mod%
    echo(
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo                 %~n0 %Copyright%
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo(
Call :Color 0E "                 [N][SSID] ================ Password" 1
echo(
(
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo                 %~n0 %Copyright%
    echo             ***********************************************
    echo(
    echo                  [N][SSID] ==============^> "Password"
    echo(

)>"%PasswordLog%"
for /f "skip=2 delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
        set "ssid=%%a"
        set "ssid=!ssid:~1!"
        call :Getpassword "!ssid!"
    )
)
echo(
echo Done
If exist "%PasswordLog%" start "" "%PasswordLog%"
pause>nul
exit
::*************************************************************************************
:Getpassword
set "name=%1"
set "name=!name:"=!"
Set "passwd="
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles %1 key^=clear ^|find /I "Cont"') do (
    set "passwd=%%a"
    Set /a Count+=1
)

If defined passwd (
    set passwd=!passwd:~1!
    echo                  [!Count!][!name!] ====^> "!passwd!"
    echo                  [!Count!][!name!] ====^> "!passwd!" >> "%PasswordLog%"
) else (
    Set /a Count+=1
call :color 0C "                 [!Count!][!name!] The Password is empty" 1
    echo                  [!Count!][!name!] The Password is empty >> "%PasswordLog%"
)
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:init
prompt $g
for /F "delims=." %%a in ('"prompt $H. & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:color
set nL=%3
if not defined nL echo requires third argument & pause > nul & goto :eof
if %3 == 0 (
    <nul set /p ".=%bs%">%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
) else if %3 == 1 (
    echo %bs%>%2 & findstr /v /a:%1 /r "^$" %2 nul & del %2 2>&1 & goto :eof
)
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:CountLines
for /f "skip=2 delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
        set /a L+=1
    )
)
set /a L=!L! + 10
Set Mod=Mode con cols=75 Lines=!L!
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not working because the path you specified to save your output text file was not getting recognized. The below code should work properly.

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show profile name=wifi_name key=clear >%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\savedpasskey.txt
@pause
```

It's always better to specify fully qualified path for the files. In this case it will be `C:\Users\<User_Name>\Desktop\savedpasskey.txt` where `%USERPROFILE%` will been replaced with `C:\Users\<User_Name>`.

Remove @pause if you don't want the command prompt to stay on screen after command is executed.